# Fishpig auto login not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento-1.9, fishpig

I have used fishpig extension in magento 1.9 and I am facing auto login error message in magento:

> WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.0.15 Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 20:20:02 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.25 Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/blog/ Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/wp/ X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Please Suggest me how to remove error message ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to help debug the issue if you posted the URL to your website.

Here are a list of points/solutions taken from the [documentation](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/auto-login/).

- Can you login manually via your browser by going to your WordPress Admin directly?
- Re-Enter the username and password after logging in manually at System > Configuration > WordPress > Auto Login
- Disable all WordPress plugins
- Are you using Cloudflare? Cloudflare can very easily stop the auto login system working.
- If this is a development site, are you using HTTP authentication? The auto login system doesn't work with HTTP authentication enabled.
- Upgrade Magento WordPress Integration to the latest version.

Comment: Hey, what if I've done all the above and still get the error? (latest version of the extension)

Comment: Double check. It may seem like you have done them all but you probably haven't. If you're sure that you've done them all then it may be a server issue related to the /etc/hosts file. You would need to speak to your hosting company about this.